# kafka-python consumer giving errors

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am fairly new to kafka and kafka-python. After installing kafka-python, I tried a naive implementation of the consumer code from here - http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html

I have been writing the consumer code from the bin directory in kafka and tried running the python code from there. However I get the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "KafkaConsumer.py", line 4, in 
>       for message in consumer:
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/vendor/six.py", line 559, in next
>       return type(self).**next**(self)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 915, in **next**
>       return next(self._iterator)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 876, in _message_generator
>       for msg in self._fetcher:
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/vendor/six.py", line 559, in next
>       return type(self).**next**(self)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/fetcher.py", line 520, in **next**
>       return next(self._iterator)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/fetcher.py", line 477, in _message_generator
>       for msg in self._unpack_message_set(tp, messages):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/consumer/fetcher.py", line 372, in _unpack_message_set
>       inner_mset = msg.decompress()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/protocol/message.py", line 121, in decompress
>       assert has_snappy(), 'Snappy decompression unsupported'
>   AssertionError: Snappy decompression unsupported

And this is the code that I have been trying to run:

```html
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer ('mytopic',bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092'], group_id='test-consumer-group')
print "Consuming messages from the given topic"
for message in consumer:
    print("%s:%d%d: key=%s value=%s"  % (message.topic, message.partition, message.offset, message.key, message.value))
```

Since, I'm really new to Kafka, I'm having trouble understanding what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing python-snappy, which is needed to read data compressed in snappy format.

You need `snappy` and `snappy-devel`, which you can install using yum, apt-get etc.
Then try `pip install python-snappy`

Comment: Hi, thank you for this suggestion. It worked. However, now all of a sudden the code gets stuck on "Consuming messages from a given topic". I have no idea why it's not printing out the data anymore. No changes have been made, it just stopped working all of a sudden.

Comment: This seems to be a separate issue. Are there any unconsumed messages left to consume in the topic? Your KafkaConsumer keeps track of messages it has consumed and will not consume messages it has already consumed. To go back to the begining call `consumer.seek_to_beginning()` before the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try consumer.seek_to_beginning() before the loop but that threw an assertion error. So, I just deleted the kafka topic, subscribed to the data I was looking for and started kafka again. For the time being, this worked. I will try to see how to change the code so that it will consume messages from the start. Thanks again for the suggestion.